# Read file into byte array is different to string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a file in visual studio with the following contents:"{"Name":"Pete"}"
If I read the file with the following code it appears to create a string with the original value:

```
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
string jsonResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```

However, the string is actually different to the version that exists if I use the following code:

```
string jsonResponse = "{\"Name\":\"Pete\"}";
```

Why?  (The reason I think it is different is because when I pass each version to a json deserializer it behaves differently)

Thanks.

Comment: In what way is the string different?

Comment: what exactly are the file contents? can you post that as a code-block without any **surrounding** quotes (but with any quotes that are actually in the file), so we can be exactly sure of the contents? Also - I assume it was *saved* with UTF8?

Comment: This is what is in the file:{"Contact":"Pete"}
Basically it starts with a bracket, and ends with a bracket and was created with VS2008.

Comment: Then the solution is easy: Your file contains "Contact", whereas your string contains "Name". ;-)

Comment: @Heinzi - well, sort of, but the point is that the json deserializer I'm using is complaining about the version that is read from the file.  When I view it in the debug window the string looks like this:
{\"Contact\":\"Pete\"}
(There is a small dot just before the opening bracket which is not showing up in this comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your final comment in the question, I suspect the problem is that you've got a [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file. Try loading the file like this instead:

```
string jsonResponse = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

I *believe* that will strip the BOM for you. Alternatively, you could try explicitly trimming it yourself:

```
jsonResponse = jsonResponse.TrimStart('\feff');
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that you have a terminating newline in your file.

You can easily verify if two strings have the same content in C# by just comparing them with `a == b`.

Here's a short code sample that might help you identify the problem. The strings are output surrounded by `< >`, which should help you identify surrounding whitespace (which, by the way, can be removed using [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx)).

```
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
string fromFile = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
string fromString = "{\"Name\":\"Pete\"}";

if (fromFile == fromString) {
    Console.WriteLine("Strings are the same.");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Strings are different!");
    Console.WriteLine("fromFile:   <" + fromFile + ">");
    Console.WriteLine("fromString: <" + fromString + ">");
}
```